# Не приходят все данные с html в js файл

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здраствуйте! У меня проблема есть html документ в smarty там есть форма с данными , есть ф-ция в js :

```
/**
 *Получение данных с формы
 *
 *obj_form -- обьект формы, в нашем случии это будет идентифекатор формы
 *hData -- массив данных с значениями name из input, textarea, select
 */
function getData(obj_form){
    var hData = {}; // инициализация пустого массива
    $('input, textarea, select', obj_form).each(function(){
        if (this.name && this.name != ''){
            hData[this.name] = this.value;
            console.log('hData[' + this.name + '] = ' + hData[this.name]);
        }
    });

    return hData;
};

    function saveOrder(){
        var postData = getData('#frmOrder'); // этой ф-цией мы собираем с формы все переменные, которые нам передаются

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: '/cart/saveorder/',
            data: postData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){
                if (data['success']){
                    alert(data['message']);
                    document.location = '/'; //редирект в корень сайта
                }
                else{
                    alert(data['message']);                
                }
            }   
        });
    }
```

Когда пробую получить данные приходят не все +

```
hData[itemCnt_12] = 1
main.js (line 87)
hData[itemPrice_12] = $item['price']
main.js (line 87)
hData[itemRealPrice_12] = 25000
main.js (line 87)
hData[adress] = г. Киев
```

Почему то $item['price'] не распознаёт.... должно приходить ещё имя, телефон с формы. Не могу понять где ошибка помогите найти. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1) Не видя кода формы, гадать можно ооочень долго.

2) А зачем велосипедить? Уж ежели юзаете jQuery используйте функцию [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) или [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
var postData = $('#frmOrder').serialize();
```

Comment: спасибо огромное